# What's better in arrays: one single for loop or to divide array in chunks and then use for loop for every chunk in php?

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have many(thousand) rows, now I want to divide data it in 3 columns so what is better option 1) using single for loop 2) divide array in 3 chunks and then use for loop for each chunk . Whose speed will be fast?

Comment: Speed is probably less relevant than which option uses excessive memory.... but why not simply run some performance tests against both options

Comment: 3) using a single foreach loop.

Comment: speed is relevant thats why asking and because of time limit i cant run performance tests on both options

Comment: `rows`? From SQL result? What PHP Version? Do you know `generators`? http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php

Comment: yes from mysql database

Comment: Did you now the terms `buffered` and `unbufferd` query? Why not using the `while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){}`?

Comment: i have used it now i want to divide data in columns (equal height) and given link is of no use for me

Comment: So you want to show about thousand+ links on page. Better get clear about what you really want to do. I dont really get it.   About preformance overall: http://www.phpbench.com/

Comment: @Mark Baker can you write your comment as answer so i can tick it as right and give me some link to test performance and speed for both options

Comment: unless you use multiple threads, it does not matter greatly. because if you have 12345 rows, you will have to **process** 12345 rows. chunking it up will only help if you parallelize the workload.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a single for loop.

But the algorithm depends on a few factors. Do we know how many rows you have? 
That way you can just divide by 3. And after the loop reaches a 3rd done, create new chunk.

Answer (score 0):

User single **`array`** and `**foreach**` to traverse the array, foreach is better one.

> foreach keep the inner pointer move forward one element each step.

or you can use [each](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) to traverse an array.

> each — Return the current key and value pair from an array and advance
>   the array cursor

```
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($para)) {
    echo $key."=".$val;
}
```

Here is an [**performance test**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php#75692) from the manual example and the result:

> Regarding speed of foreach vs while(list) =each I wrote a benchmark
>   script and the results are that clearly foreach is faster. MUCH
>   faster. Even with huge arrays (especially with huge arrays). I tested
>   with sizes 100,000. 1,000,000 and 10,000,000. To do the test with 10
>   million i had to set my memory limit real high, it was close to 1gb by
>   the time it actually worked. Anyways,

```
> <?php function getDiff($start, $end) {
>     $s = explode(' ', $start);
>     $stot = $s[1] + $s[0];
>     $e = explode(' ', $end);
>     $etot = $e[1] + $e[0];
>     return $etot - $stot; }
> 
> $lim=10000000; $arr = array(); for ($i=0; $i<$lim; $i++) {
>     $arr[$i] = $i/2; }
> 
> $start = microtime(); foreach ($arr as $key=>$val);
> 
> $end = microtime(); echo "time for foreach = " . getDiff($start, $end)
> . ".\n";
> 
> reset($arr); $start = microtime(); while (list($key, $val) =
> each($arr)); $end = microtime(); echo "time list each = " .
> getDiff($start, $end) . ".\n"; ?>
> 
> here are some of my results: with 1,000,000 time for foreach =
> 0.0244591236115. time list each = 0.158002853394. desktop:/media/sda5/mpwolfe/tests$ php test.php time for foreach =
> 0.0245339870453. time list each = 0.154260158539. desktop:/media/sda5/mpwolfe/tests$ php test.php time for foreach =
> 0.0269000530243. time list each = 0.157305955887.
> 
> then with 10,000,000: desktop:/media/sda5/mpwolfe/tests$ php test.php
> time for foreach = 1.96586894989. time list each = 14.1371650696.
> desktop:/media/sda5/mpwolfe/tests$ php test.php time for foreach =
> 2.02504014969. time list each = 13.7696218491. desktop:/media/sda5/mpwolfe/tests$ php test.php time for foreach =
> 2.0246758461. time list each = 13.8425710201.
> 
> by the way, these results are with php 5.2 i believe, and a linux
> machine with 3gb of ram and 2.8ghz dual core pentium
```

Comment: But `foreach` makes an copy of the array first, thats why generators are know supported by php. `for` is the better choice on indexed arrays.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions: no you can use a reference to the original array like that: `foreach($array as $k=>&$v)`

Comment: To complex to explain it here, read here: https://nikic.github.io/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html    maybe not on all php versions, but it does it in given cases.

Comment: dont write code i know how to code just say in terms of speed which option will be better

Comment: Argh!!: `while (list ($key, $val) = each ($para))` (the slowest way to iterate an array straight from PHP3)

Answer (score 0):

as commented by Franz Gleichmann in my case this was right answer "unless you use multiple threads, it does not matter greatly. because if you have 12345 rows, you will have to process 12345 rows. chunking it up will only help if you parallelize the workload."